# Merging cells of a row of data grid view in C# windows application

Tags: c#

Is it possible to merge two or more cells of a particular row of data grid view in C# windows application?

Comment: You will have to describe what you mean by 'merging' to make this a real question.

Comment: i needed to show some row as a single column

Comment: I think OP means in the same way you can highlight two table cells in Dreamweaver and merge them into one, two column, row cell.

Comment: If its just about 'showing', why not get rid of the borders?

Comment: The question is rather vague, which I guess is why it's on negative one right now. I guess that they're trying to get a datagridview with say four columns and four rows, maybe 12 cells populated with data but with the third row being a single column across? So, where does it get its data from? Ultimately, they can't do it without some heavy manipulation of the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

Quickedy quick Google search turns up this.

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=415930

But no, natively you can't - Datagridviews are not equal to HTML tables or Excel sheets. They simply take the datasource that is bound to them and (after some optional trickery) present the datasource in columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own column class by inheriting the DataGridViewColumn class or any of its derived classes to provide custom appearance, behavior, or hosted controls. For more information, see [Custom Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43.aspx)

<strike>Yes, You will have to use `DataTemplate` within a `TemplatedColumn`</strike>

and Bind the data to two separate textblocks within the template.

Comment: Bzzzz, it is a windows app, not web app.

Comment: @leppie: Corrected that. I meant custom column.